# Change border color of Button on PointerOver

Tags: wpf, windows-8.1

I have a Button with ControlTemplate:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Border BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="2">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStopCollection>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="LimeGreen"></GradientStop>
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="LightBlue"></GradientStop>
                        </GradientStopCollection>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

<Button Margin="10" Width="110" Padding="5" Height="30"                   
                    Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}">Test</Button>
```

Now I want to change of border color when mouse pointer over the button.
Here is my version:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Border x:Name="Border"  BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="2">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="LimeGreen"></GradientStop>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="LightBlue"></GradientStop>
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" /> 
        </Border>
        <VisualStateManager>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

But it returns too many errors.  For example, "Property VisualTree can be defined only one time". How can I fix it?

Comment: It's complaining because template has both `Border` and `VisualStateManager`. Instead of `VisualStateManager` tag try using `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` tag

Comment: Thanks. Error messages disappeared, but I can not see my button in this case.

Comment: `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` must be set against root element of `ControlTemplate` so need to move it to `Border` or, for example, create a `Grid` around `Border` and `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups`

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you pls write it as answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because `ControlTemplate` has 2 root elements `Border` and `VisualStateManager`. Instead of `VisualStateManager` you need to set `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups`and it needs to be set against root element of the `ControlTemplate` so either move it into `Border` or create, for example, `Grid` around both `Border` and `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
   <Grid>
      <Border x:Name="Border"  BorderBrush="Orange" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="2">
         <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
               <GradientStopCollection>
                  <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="LimeGreen"/>
                  <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="LightBlue"/>
               </GradientStopCollection>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
         </Border.Background>
         <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" /> 
      </Border>
      <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
         <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
               <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
         </VisualStateGroup>
      </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```